# Why does command apt-cache show result in "E: no packages found"? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, apt-cache

I don't understand why my apt-cache would be empty, as there is a gazillion packages installed on my system (like all Ubuntu systems). I tried installing a random program and running it thinking that it might just show temporary packages, but got the same result.

Comment: Did you try to execute `apt-get update` to update the package index?

Comment: In any case the error message is quite unhelpful. Instead of being `E: no packages found` it should be something like `E: missing operand package name` or similar that *might* give a hint that it's *on the command line* that something is missing, not on the system.

Comment: What exactly you ran? `apt-cache show sdjaf` shows "E: No packages found", because sdjaf isn't a package that exist in the package lists.

Answer (score 9):

The `apt-cache show` (or `apt show`) command needs an argument: the name of a package:

```
$ apt-cache show gimp
Package: gimp
Priority: optional
Section: universe/graphics
Installed-Size: 16188
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Ari Pollak <ari@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.8.18-1
```

... and many more lines

Perhaps you want `apt list` to see available packages or `apt list --installed` for installed packages?

Comment: lol, was just looking at some notes i made and it appears i was confused about the purpose of the program due to some shitty note taking...this thread should be removed

Comment: Hehe well I guess others could make the same mistake @thinksinbinary

Comment: @thinksinbinary Somehow this made it to the Hot Network Questions list, so apparently enough find it interesting...